# How to write mockito test for post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

This function is used to update the user details in the database. can someone help me to write test cases for this function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateVendorDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("users") Users users, BindingResult result,Model model) {
        logger.info("{}.{}",new VendorController().getClass().getPackageName(), new VendorController().getClass().getName());

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("edit","edit");
            logger.warn("Function: updateVendorDetails(), Information: Error while updating vendor details");
            return register.toString();
        }
        userDao.updateVendorDetails(users);
        logger.info("Function: updateVendorDetails(), Information: Vendor details updated successfully");
        return vendor.toString();
    }
```

**Update**

Code:

mockMvc.perform(post("/updateDetails").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).params(params)).andExpect(status().isOk());

Resulting error:

> *This says that post method is forbidden and my test fails*

This is my Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestVendorPage {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }




    @WithMockUser(roles = "VENDOR")
    @Test
    public void testIfUpdateEdtailsIsAvailableOnlyForVendor() throws Exception {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        params.add("firstName", "vinod");
        params.add("lastName", "babu");
        params.add("contactNumber", "9952016709");
        mockMvc.perform(post("/updateDetails").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).params(params)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add some code on what you have tried so far in writing mockito test. what issue you faced ?

Comment: We can't just tell you how to "test this method".  You need to learn how to test.  SUGGESTION: Please consider working through any/all of these tutorials: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing, https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/, https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-integration-test-example/

Comment: mockMvc.perform(post("/updateDetails").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).params(params)).andExpect(status().isOk());

Comment: This says that post method is forbidden and my test fails

Comment: @AMITHSAI, are you able to hit successfully with postman ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your update:

1. Thank you for clarifying your post with a specific error/specific problem.
2. For that specific error -  `HTTP 403: Forbidden` - this should resolve the problem:

   [Unit test Springboot MockMvc returns 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387926/3135317)

> i think probleam is happend in "mockMvc" object is not
>   autowired.mockMvc object should load from WebApplicationContext in
>   before program run.

3. Please - *PLEASE* - consider looking at one or more of the links I cited above.

   - [baeldung.com: Testing in Spring Boot](https://baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)
   - [spring.io: Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web)
   - [mkyong.com: Spring REST Integration Example](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-integration-test-example/)

I've found all three sites very valuable resources.  Time spent with these tutorials will help you a great deal!

Comment: well i have autowired the webApplicationContext. Sorry i didn't post the entire code. But it still gives the same forbidden error.